# DeviceInfo native module is not installed correctly

Tags: facebook, react-native, react-native-ios

[image]

So I tried implementing Facebook Login and followed all the steps accordingly. After having errors with `FBSDKcorekit/FBSDKcorekit.h' file not found`, I decided to pivot over to working on other components.

Lo' and behold, I have this error giving me trouble now. I followed along with this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rAXVKapP5cM&t=458s where I used the `react-native install react-native-fbsdk` and `react-native link react-native-fbsdk` commands in my terminal.

If it helps, I'm getting the following compile error in my terminal:
The following build commands failed:

```
CompileC /Users/someUser/desiredProject/ios/build/Build/Intermediates/RCTFBSDK.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/RCTFBSDK.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/RCTFBSDKGraphRequestManager.o RCTFBSDK/core/RCTFBSDKGraphRequestManager.m normal x86_64 objective-c com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
```

(1 failure)

I'm not sure if it was the tinkering around with the `react-native-fbsdk` or making links to it that caused this error. Note my project was working before I was trying to implement Facebook Login and using the `link` command.

What's going on here?

Thanks in advance for your time and patience.

edit: Also I did not implement any of the Facebook login code yet since I couldn't get a successful build on Xcode.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

@kdizzle Make sure you have the right packager running in the terminal, sometimes you may have a packager associated with another react native project running, this happens because when you stop running an xcode RN project, it doesn't stop the packager in the terminal, and when you start/open another RN project in xcode, it simply checks if a packager is running, doesn't check if it's associated with the current project. So make sure you stop all of the packager instances in the terminal and then open the RN project again.

Comment: I'm having the same error and I'm running just one application, so I don't think it's relevant. I just upgraded to the new version of react native and I got this.

Comment: @SVN cool that worked for me! I just shut down all my applications running and started the project back up the next day. I feel pretty silly now, but thank you shedding light on what was happening.

Comment: I am also facing same issue, answer did not work for me!

Comment: @danielebertella and Williams - answer did not work for me either. This happened on upgrade to RN v.44 - have either of you found a solution yet?

Comment: @Turnipdabeets I think you are not running `react-native` server of correct application which you are trying to run on device

Comment: @Williams what do you mean? I only have one app running - is that what you mean?

Comment: Worked for me too.

Comment: @Turnipdabeets I mean that you have started react native server linked with XYZ app and trying to open some different XYZ1 app

Comment: @Turnipdabeets we had a similar issue after "updating" because we slightly changed the name / bundle-id of our app. Our Android test device still had an old app installed. When using deep links to start the app, we always saw this error message as it probably opened the old one but tried using the newer react-native packager stuff. Uninstalling the app(s) from the device helped.

Comment: excellent, that is exactly issue I had.  Much appreciated, voted up

Answer (score 8):

This may happen when upgrading a project to a newer version of react-native. To fix it,

1. Stop your packager.
2. Quit your iOS/android simulator.
3. Reinstall your modules: `rm -rf node_modules && npm install`
4. Restart your packager and simulator, e.g. `react-native run-ios`

Comment: How do you stop the packager?

Answer (score 2):

I had this issue and it happened when I changed Hardware within the simulator.  To fix it I had to kill the packager and run 'react-native run-ios' again.  It didn't happen all the time but when it did this fixed it for me!

Answer (score 1):

Another use is in a Brownfield App. Check your iOS and/or Android react-native versions. If they don't match exactly you will see this error screen too.

For example: I had a react native instance running 0.45.1 while Android had 0.45.0 installed. The solution for me was to make sure everything was running the same version.

Answer (score 0):

None of the above answers have worked for me, so I researched the 'react-native' options a little and ended up:

1. Deleting the iOS and android folders from the app directory altogether
2. Running 'react-native eject'
3. Re-running 'react-native run-ios'

After that the iPhone emulator seemed to have no problem with the app.

Answer (score -1):

This problem would appear when React Native libraries in ios project can not found.
I happend to meet this problem when i update my react-native version from 0.42 to 0.44, and cause that a file named RCTConvert+Map disappear in 0.44, so i update my pod.
command: `pod update`