# DeviceInfo native module is not installed correctly in react native

Tags: android, react-native

Hi I am trying to run my `react-native` android application on the device. It was working well, suddenly I am getting an error on running application.

> DeviceInfo native module is not installed correctly

I have checked this [DeviceInfo native module is not installed correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43727332/deviceinfo-native-module-is-not-installed-correctly) but it did not work for me. I restarted my system to kill all process.

Can anyone help me how to solve this issue ?

[image]

```
D:\React Native\ReduxExample1>react-native -v
react-native-cli: 2.0.1
react-native: 0.44.0

D:\React Native\ReduxExample1>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was running different application which is also built in `react-native` but did not run `react-native` server of that application. This was just my bad :)

Answer (score 0):

I think this type of errors when you are not in the right packages. So as per my experience Make sure you have the right packager running in the terminal, sometimes you may have a packager associated with another react native project running, this happens because when you stop running a React Native project from Xcode or  Android Studio, it doesn't stop the packager in the terminal, and when you start/open another React Native project in  Xcode or  Android Studio, it simply checks if a packager is running, doesn't check if it's associated with the current project. So make sure you stop all of the packager instances in the terminal and then open the React Native project again.