# React-Native Android: DeviceInfo native module is not installed correctly

Tags: android, firebase, react-native

Since **upgrading to react-native 0.44**, I've had this issue on Android only (iOS works fine) :

[image]

I've tried: `rm -rf ./node-modules && yarn` to no avail.

I am running only one packager and it's for the correct application (this is in reference to [these](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43781196/deviceinfo-native-module-is-not-installed-correctly-in-react-native) [two](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43727332/deviceinfo-native-module-is-not-installed-correctly) posts)

To run my app, I hit run in Android Studio with a packager running and it launches my app in the Emulator.

Running it with `react-native run-android` doesn't work - it complains about something else :

> - What went wrong:
>     A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
>
>   > Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':app:_debugApk'.
>   >     A problem occurred configuring project ':react-native-firebase'.
>   >     The SDK Build Tools revision (23.0.3) is too low for project ':react-
>   >     native-firebase'. Minimum required is 25.0.0

I'm less concerned about the latter since I was able to run the app from Android Studio, but if you have a solution for this one too, I'll take it :)

Any idea why it's complaining about the DeviceInfo module ?

Comment: Try with update our SDK build tools version and `buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"` to `buildToolsVersion "25.0.0"` change in `your-project/android/app/build.gradle`

Comment: That is already the case, in my `app/build.gradle` I have the following: `android { 
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion '25.0.0'`